# Is there any reason to have a constructor if you have an interface for a class in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Like the title says, is there any reason I should have a constructor if my class allready has implemented an interface? It seems to me like it's duplicated code.

```
interface PersonInterface  {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    email: string;
}

class Person implements PersonInterface {

    firstname = "John";
    lastname = "Johnsson";
    email = "John.jonson@mail.com"

    PrintPerson() {
        console.log(`${this.firstname}, ${this.lastname}, ${this.email}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: An interface just provides definitions but with no implementations. (an abstract class would be a partial implementation of an interface)  But if that's all your class is doing, you don't need to explicitly define a constructor. You're not binding anything or initializing state.

Comment: Side note: The *overwhelmingly common* convention in JavaScript and TypeScript is that method names start with a lowercase letter (`printPerson` rather than `PrintPerson`). You can obviously do what you like in your own code, but sticking to conventions makes it easier to have other people working with you on the code and (for example) helping you with it here. :-)

Comment: @Phaelaxz - Well, they're initializing state, they're just doing it with property initializers rather than constructor code. (Although it ends up in the same place.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Person` class has a constructor, it's just one that's generated for you. (It assigns those values to the public properties.) There's no reason to have an explicit one unless you need to do something the generated constructor won't do for you.

(But this has nothing to do with having implemented an interface. The same would be true if your class didn't have `implements PersonInterface`. The fact you're implementing an interface isn't related to whether you need a constructor.)

Comment: This clears things up for me.. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, with typescript, we implement Interface to make properties of our class strictly typed. But constructors are automatically generated for you and can be modified if you need them. Basically, interface and constructors are two different cases of OOP so there is no reason to have a constructor as it gets automatically generated if you have implemented Interface with your class.

Comment: *"Usually, with typescript, we implement Interface to make properties of our class strictly typed."* Can you explain what you mean by that? Properties of a class like the OP's `Person` are strictly typed with or without an interface.

Comment: *"...there is no reason to have a constructor as it gets automatically generated if you have implemented Interface with your class"* It's created whether you implement an interface or not.

Comment: "Properties of a class like the OP's Person are strictly typed with or without an interface." yeah you are right but with typescript, the type for the properties of the class are mostly defined on the Interfaces as it improves the Persistence of the code. For Example, a class with an id of type number could be written as a string in another class. This could lead to many issues in the future. But once the type of the properties is defined in Interface and both the classes implement it then there is no chance of the property id being of two different types. This improves type safety.

Comment: " It's created whether you implement an interface or not." yes, I also mean the same but just answering it in the way how the question was asked.